# Backup в php без использования сторонних библиотек

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel-5.6

Я создал контроллер, который делает backup файлов в виде *SQL* запросов и сохраняет все данные в файл *backup.sql*. Но мне потребовали соблюдать следующие:

1. Скрипт должен учитывать количество таблиц в БД.
2. Скрипт должен учитывать количество и объем данных в таблице.

То есть, мне нужно учитывать ограничения по времени выполнения скрипта и ограничения по памяти. Для этого, Я создал констант и сравниваю, если размер файла превыщает констант, то файл не скачивается, в противном случае то можно скачать. У меня вопрос:

Это вообще правильное решение? Спасибо за ранее. Вот часть моего кода:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;
use Illuminate\Database\Events\StatementPrepared; // set the fetch mode
use Carbon\Carbon;
use DB;
use App\Post;
use App\User;

date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Samara');

class BackupController extends Controller
{
    const MAX_VALUE = 200000; //kilobytes 
    // const MAX_VALUE = 9; //kilobytes 

    public function lockTable()
    {
        // lock all tables
        DB::unprepared('FLUSH TABLES WITH READ LOCK;');
    }

    public function unlockTable()
    {
        // unlock all tables
        DB::unprepared('UNLOCK TABLES');
    }

    public function queryFetch($data)
    {
        $pdo  = DB::connection()->getPdo();
        $stmt = $pdo->prepare($data);
        $stmt->execute();
        // $stmt = $pdo->query($data);
        $results = $stmt->fetch();
        return $results;
    }

    public function create(Request $request)
    {
        $this->setPdoMode();
        $numTables = DB::select("SHOW TABLES");
        $countUserRecords = User::count();
        $countPostRecords = Post::count();

        return view('backup', compact('numTables','countUserRecords', 'countPostRecords'));
    }

    public function setPdoMode()
    {
        \Event::listen(StatementPrepared::class, function($event) {
        $event->statement->setFetchMode(\PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);});
    }

    public function backup(Request $request)
    {
        if ($request->all()) {
            $tables = request('table');
            $output = '';     
            foreach ($tables as $key => $table) {   
                $this->lockTable();
                $show_table_query = $this->queryFetch("SHOW CREATE TABLE {$table}");
                $output .="\n" . $show_table_query[1] . ";\n";
                $this->setPdoMode();
                $single_result = DB::select("SELECT * FROM {$table}");
                $output .= $this->getTableData($single_result, $table);
            }
            if ($this->checkFileSize($output)) {
                return redirect()->route('create'); 
            }                  
        }             
            return redirect()->route('backupError'); 
    }

    // Stores the file in this location: storage/app
    public function download($output)
    {
        $dt = Carbon::now();
        $file_name = 'backup_on[' . $dt->format('y-m-d H-i-s') . '].sql';
        Storage::disk('local')->put($file_name, $output);
    }

    public function getTableData($single_result, $table) 
    {
        $this->unlockTable();
        $output = '';
        foreach ($single_result as $key => $table_val) {  
            $output .= "\nINSERT INTO $table("; 
            $output .= "" .addslashes(implode(", ", array_keys($table_val))) . ") VALUES(";
            $output .= "'" . addslashes(implode("','", array_values($table_val))) . "');\n";
        }   
        return $output;
    }

    public function checkFileSize($file)
    {
        $file_size = strlen($file);
        // convert bytes to kilobytes 
        $file_size = round($file_size / 1024, 0, PHP_ROUND_HALF_UP);
        if ($file_size <= self::MAX_VALUE) {
            $this->download($file);
            return true;
         } 
        return false;               
    }
}
```

*Мой вопрос:* Как обойти ограничение по времени выполнения скрипта и ограничения по памяти?

Comment: Мой вопрос. Как обойти ограничение по времени выполнения скрипта и ограничения по памяти? Спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

Снять ограничения

```
set_time_limit(0);
ini_set('memory_limit', '-1');
```

только по моему делать бекап на лету не самое лучшее решение. Подойдет только для небольших баз. Могут, кстати, еще быть ограничения веб-сервера по таймауту ожидания ответа от скрипта.

Лучше запустить сохранение бекапа в фоне. Сохранять во временный файл. Попутно где-то через каждые N циклов сохранять прогресс, который можно читать ajax-ом со страницы. Как только бекап завершится - отдать файл.

Comment: Dmitry, спасибо за ответ! Дело в том что, снять ограничения считается bad practice. Кстати, вы смгли бы показать на примерах как запустить сохранение бекапа в фоне?

Comment: Ну например, если у вас nginx и fast-cgi то можно воспользоваться функцией http://php.net/manual/ru/function.fastcgi-finish-request.php . Серверу придет ответ "бекап начался" и javascrip-ом периодически дергать состояние